# How can i use mocking in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new with unit testing and i am trying to learn mocking with jest
i have a code with 2 folder: App.js (code), add.test.js(test)

before writing mock statement `jest.mock('../App');` test was succeed
but after i typed it to mocking the test failed with this error

```
error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
Expected: "add"
Received: undefined
```

i do not know what is the error

App.js

```
  const add = () => {
  return "add";
};


module.exports = { add };
```

add.test.js

```
const addFun = require("../App");

jest.mock('../App');

it("mocks entire module", () => {
  expect(addFun.add.mock).toBeTruthy();
});

it("pre add function", () => {
  expect(addFun.add()).toBe("add");
});
```

Comment: Why would anything need to be mocked here? You have a single pure function with no collaborators.

Comment: just for learning ! i use simple example to track the error and recognize it

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the App module and asserting the behaviour of the mocked add function. You are trying to directly use addFun.add() without providing a mocked return value for it. Something like this should work,

```js
it("pre add function", () => {
    // Since you're mocking the entire module, you can directly use the mock function
    addFun.add.mockReturnValue("mocked add") // Mock the return value
    expect(addFun.add()).toBe("mocked add") // Test the function using the mock return value
})
```